# Why do I need to specify the props type if I supply a generic type to a React.FC?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the `@typescript-eslint/typedef` rule turned on to enforrce type definitions on parameters. However, when I generically type a `React.FC`, I get an error:

`export const Address: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props) => (`

> expected props to have a type annotationeslint(@typescript-eslint/typedef)

I had expected the `props` argument's type to be inferred by the generic type applied to the function component.

To remove the error, I need to explicitly type `props`:

`export const Address: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = (props: Props) => (`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/typedef.md your rule will enforce types even if they can be inferred:

```
When Not To Use It
If you are using stricter TypeScript compiler options, 
particularly --noImplicitAny and/or --strictPropertyInitialization, 
you likely don't need this rule.

In general, if you do not consider the cost of writing unnecessary 
type annotations reasonable, then do not use this rule.
```

They also mention you might not need to use it:

```
Note: requiring type annotations unnecessarily can be cumbersome to 
maintain and generally reduces code readability. TypeScript is often 
better at inferring types than easily written type annotations would 
allow. Instead of enabling typedef, it is generally recommended to use the 
--noImplicitAny and/or --strictPropertyInitialization compiler options to 
enforce type annotations only when useful.
```

Comment: Indeed, looks like I was getting a bit too enthusiastic with my linting!

Comment: glad I could help :)